# How to limit requests based on source IP on Istio

Tags: limit, istio, rate-limiting, envoyproxy

I am using istio version 1.12.

I tried to add limit configuration but it can't limit requests based on source IP.Does Istio support this?

I am using the official sample：
https://istio.io/v1.12/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/#global-rate-limit

Comment: Please add your yaml file(s).

Comment: my yaml from：<https://istio.io/v1.12/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/#global-rate-limit>

Answer (score 0):

You can use **remote_address** key.

ConfigMap changes ratelimit service:

```
      - key: remote_address
        rate_limit:
          requests_per_unit: 10
          unit: second
```

Restart the ratelimit service.

Envoyfilter changes:

```
            - actions:
              - remote_address: {}
```

See also: https://github.com/neumanndaniel/kubernetes/tree/master/envoy-ratelimit

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I can see remote ip in redis keys, but it still doesn't work.
We decided to rate limit in other ways so as not to put more pressure on istio.
Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking into this, I was able to configure this per remote address and Path (at the start it was failling due to the order of the actions).

Example config:

```
config.yaml: |
  domain: ingress
  descriptors:
  - key: PATH  # global limit per ip address
    descriptors:
    - key: remote_address
      rate_limit:
        unit: minute
        requests_per_unit: 100
  - key: PATH
    value: "/example/*"  # limit to any url starting with /example/
    descriptors:
    - key: remote_address
      rate_limit:
        unit: minute
        requests_per_unit: 10
```

And the actions are defined as this:

```
rate_limits:
  - actions:
    - request_headers:
        header_name: ":path"
        descriptor_key: "PATH"
    - remote_address: {}
```

**Be sure that the order of the actions matches the order of the descriptors, if you want to match for remote_address first, put that first and then the headers.**

I configure this using istio on the ingress gateway side, following mainly this [document](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/) and this [example](https://github.com/envoyproxy/ratelimit/tree/main/examples)